# How to pass output from UFT test to Jenkins console

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft

Does anybody experience or any idea with pass output from UFT test to Jenkins console?
I started a UFT test through Jenkins and I use *.mtbx files for pass parameters from Jenkins to test but now I need some data (for example order id or phone number) from test pass to Jenkins console.
Is there any option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only alone option is to write a file in run time and enter your data in it.
At the end of exectution, you should call the same file through jenkins.
Regards,
Prem Padayachi